# Problems with Z-index while browsing my page in mobile

Tags: html, css, z-index

I  have created a portfolio page for myself.

https://alonoparag.github.io/index.html#home

My problem is that when I check the page using Google Developers tools or with my android (samsung galaxy s4) device, the navbar's  items are always behind the content of #home.

I tried tweaking the z index of the navbar items versus the home content, with no avail. When Checking the elements in the developer's tools I saw that both the navbar elements and the div z-index have changed, but it didn't affected the way that the elements are stacked.

I would appreciate help with this.

Cheers

here's my code

```
.topnav.responsive a {
   float: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
   z-index: 10000;
}

div.content {
   align-content: center;
   width: 85%;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 16px;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give a position for z-index to work. So if you add `position:relative; z-index:10;` to your header, it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a (static) position, for example.

```
position: relative;
```

or

```
position: fixed;
```

"z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default)." - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: I tried using your solution, but it didn't seem to solve the problem, even when each element is given a position other than static, they still stack over the navbar items.

Answer (score 2):

The one issue I found is that the parent `#home` container itself seems to be the one giving you grief. Here are some tweaks I made in the developer console on my end. I tested it on a full desktop view as well as shrunk it down in the mobile preview and it worked properly.

**CSS:**

```
#home {
   z-index: 1;
}

#myTopnav {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

**In addition, make sure to establish a position value for your elements.**

That should do the trick for you!

Comment: That's just because he's set a position to the #myTopnav element. Using your answer he can fall into the same trap again next time.